# sqlConnection->Open() don't work

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++, ado.net, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio->Resources->Data base connection->MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider) fill all in `server`, `user`, `password`.

Connection open correctly. In server viewer I can see database I need and I can send queries to tables via **`rightmousebutton`** click menu.

[image]

BUT!!!

Trying to open connection in program code. Copy connection string from database properties. ERROR.

[image]

Tried many from connection string.com another variants connection strings( user id, password и etc.), firewall off, MySQL connectors installed, Ado.Net connectors installed, root rights granted. I cant understand why it's not work. Here is the code for open connection:

`String^ connectionstring = "server=localhost;database=users;persist security info=True;user id=root;password=12345;";
SqlConnection^sqlConnection = gcnew SqlConnection(connectionstring);
sqlConnection->Open();`

Comment: A long time ago there was the same problem with the `connection string`. At that time, the `connection string` appeared to be normal. I need some code.

Comment: If you're not going to translate the error message to English, try https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: 20 views / 0 answers in RU...

Comment: Did you expect every one of those 20 people to know what's wrong with your code? If you are going to use the English version, the least you can do is use English. Posts in other languages tend to get downvoted and closed as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

3 days left burning and SELF SOLVE!!!!

1.Go to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/MySql/, download free lite version connector

2.`using namespaces Devar::Data::MySql;` in namespaces

3.

```
String^ connectionstring = "User Id=root;Password=12345;Host=127.0.0.1;database=users;"; // connectionstring
MySqlConnection^Connection = gcnew MySqlConnection(connectionstring); // new object
Connection->Open(); // open
MySqlCommand^command = /*....... // queries in database
....*/
Connection->Close(); // close
```

4. Help file to connector https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/MySql/docs/

PS. I dont why only this connector work in my case but seems its problems in my Visual Studio or MySQL Server.